# Android (or Java perhaps) unfamiliar "throw" usage

Tags: java, android, function, exception, throws

I found an unfamiliar usage of "throws" in Android sample code like below.

```
public Void handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException
{
  ...
}
```

I just want to know how this "throws" works in this case.
I posted this since it was a bit hard to find appropriate search word go google.

Comment: This is just Java, and should be covered by *any* beginner's Java book. Stack Overflow is great for specific problems, but it's really not suitable to learn a language from scratch - you should read a good book or tutorial.

Comment: http://bit.ly/VvEoJN Second link googling for "java throws keyword".

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing `throws` and `throw`.

`throws` indicates in the method's signature that it can throw an `IOException` in some cases.
`throw new IOException()` will throw the actual exception.

The `throws` keyword can be seen in every Java program, and forces you to encapsulate your method call in a `try {} catch(){}` block if the exception is a [checked exception](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions)

Comment: nice idea to think this way, guess so too, by what he asked

Answer (score 1):

The `throws` keyword after the method declaration indicates that this method **might** throw this exception. It means that any calling method must ensure that they catch this exception, like this:

```
...
try {
  var.handleResponse(response);
catch (IOException e) {
  // oops, something went wrong
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This is the first time to see "throws" keyword in declaration. And I understood it from your simple & nice explanation.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in the body of the function `handleResponse()` there is a *possibility* of an IOException being thrown. when you call the function you will need to surround it in `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

`IOException` is a checked Exception and therefore the `throws IOException` is required if your code inside the method can throw an `IOException` (and you are not catching it inside the method). This wouldn't be required if `IOException` would be a RuntimeException (like `NullPointerException`). Maybe you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) question.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). From the same tutorial:

> All methods use the throw statement to throw an exception. The throw statement requires a single argument: a throwable object. Throwable objects are instances of any subclass of the Throwable class. Here's an example of a throw statement.

```
    throw someThrowableObject;
```